# Is Visual Studio 2010 WebDev WebServer (Cassini) 64-bit compatible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, cassini, webdev.webserver

I'm now developing on Visual Studio 2008 on a 64-bit OS (Windows Server 2008 64-bit).

While the apps I write are 64-bit capable, as is IIS7, the built-in ASP.NET Development Server (aka Cassini aka WebDev.Webserver.exe) runs as 32-bit.

This brings up a plethora of issues, such as:

- 32-bit and 64-bit applications have separate HKLM\Software registry homes
- There are 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the SQL Server Client Network Utility
- Other fun surprises I haven't discovered but I'm sure will spring up

While I am finding workarounds for most of this, I have to ask...

Does anyone who has played with the Visual Studio 2010 preview bits on 64-bit architecture know if the development web servers can handle 64-bit, and if so, are there options for which mode to run it in?  (Like a checkbox in the project properties, for instance)

Comment: I have to add that currently on VS2008, I used Reflector to output the source of the Cassini executable and successfully recompiled it to support 64-bit, and have been using that fairly successfully - however since I am on a Server OS it is usually easier to just use IIS for debugging.  If VS2010 does not support a 64-bit debugging webserver, I'll probably end up doing the exact same thing once I get my hands on the bits after official release.

Comment: The different registry can cause unexpected and strange errors. As you're dealing with a different registry, you don't get exceptions- you're just missing the keys you expect to be there. I'm concerned for the same reasons you are, that these little 'surprises' aren't clear to the developer until there's a problem. Using IIS Express seems like the best option, if that one exists.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Full source code for a direct replacement for VS2008/2010 dev servers is available at http://cassinidev.codeplex.com. You can compile to x64 to support your requirements.

Comment: asked if [CassiniDev works with VS 2012 RC on CodePlex discussion](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/discussions/358888)

Comment: Wouldn't have thought of doing this if I hadn't seen it here. Works perfectly in VS2012.

Answer (score 3):

32 bit IDE and related things make it easier to develop.

When you start to test and deploy further, such as x64, IIS is a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://sites.google.com/site/csharpstuff1/CassiniDevx64.zip?attredirects=0&d=1) is x64 built version of cassini web server (only binaries for VS2008 and VS2010).

I just went to http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/, and built the source code in x64 mode.

Resulting binaries worked for me, when I replace them as stated here: http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visual%20Studio%202008%2f2010%20Development%20server%20drop-in%20replacement&referringTitle=Documentation

You can download binaries here:
https://sites.google.com/site/csharpstuff1/CassiniDevx64.zip?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: The 4.0 exe I downloaded worked (I placed them in the program files (x86) path.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this guy took a similar approach to using Reflector and re-compiling as 64 bit:
http://codeka.com/blogs/index.php/2007/06/18/64_bit_webdev_webserver_exe

I haven't found anything that suggests the story will be different in VS2010, but fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1):

There's a third-party product called UltiDev Cassini that advertises a 64bit version. It's free and redistributable; that may solve your needs.

Information here: http://ultidev.com/Products/Cassini/CassiniDevGuide.htm