# Serializing to MemoryStream causes an OutOfmemoryException, but serializing to a FileStream does not. Can anyone tell me why?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft Json.Net to serialize objects as json. I continually run into an **OutOfMemoryException** when I try to serialize to a **MemoryStream**, but not when I serialize to a **FileStream**.  Could someone explain why this might be happening?  These are the two methods that I am using to serialize.

**Throws an OutOfMemoryException**

```
        private static MemoryStream _serializeJson<T>(T obj)
    {
        try
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
            var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter);
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            serializer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, obj);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Logger.WriteError(e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Doesn't throw an OutOfMemoryException**

```
    private static void _serializeJsonToFile<T>(T obj, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                serializer.Serialize(jw, obj);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

P.S. some might ask why I would want to return a stream instead of simply serializing to the file stream.  This is because I want to keep serialization in one class and file handling in another, so I'm passing the memory stream to a WriteFile method in another class later.

Comment: How big are the objects you are serializing?

Comment: The file size is 17.8 MB.

Comment: Try to Dispose `MemoryStream`,  `StreamWriter` and `JsonTextWriter`. Of course `MemoryStream` in consumer class/method.

Comment: If I dispose the MemoryStream, how could I use it later?

Comment: Refer to the excellent answer in this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595061/outofmemoryexception-while-populating-memorystream-256mb-allocation-on-16gb-sys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting OutOfMemoryExceptions because the memory stream is very aggressive about it's growth. Every time it needs to re-size it doubles it's internal buffer.

```
//The code from MemoryStream http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs.html#1416df83d2368912
private bool EnsureCapacity(int value) {
    // Check for overflow
    if (value < 0)
        throw new IOException(Environment.GetResourceString("IO.IO_StreamTooLong"));
    if (value > _capacity) {
        int newCapacity = value;
        if (newCapacity < 256)
            newCapacity = 256;
        // We are ok with this overflowing since the next statement will deal
        // with the cases where _capacity*2 overflows.
        if (newCapacity < _capacity * 2)
            newCapacity = _capacity * 2;
        // We want to expand the array up to Array.MaxArrayLengthOneDimensional
        // And we want to give the user the value that they asked for
        if ((uint)(_capacity * 2) > Array.MaxByteArrayLength)
            newCapacity = value > Array.MaxByteArrayLength ? value : Array.MaxByteArrayLength;

        Capacity = newCapacity;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

With a 17.8 MB file that is a worst case scenario of a 35.6 MB byte array being used. The old byte arrays that where discarded during the resizing process can also cause [Memory Fragmentation](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/performance/the-top-5-.net-memory-management-misconceptions/#misconception5) depending on how long they live, this can easily get your program to throw a OOM error before you get to the 32 bit memory limit.

Writing directly to a FileStream does not require any large buffers to be created in memory so it uses much less space.

There is a way to separate the logic of the saving from the serializing, just pass in the stream to the function instead of creating it in the function itself.

```
private static void _serializeJson<T>(T obj, Stream stream)
{
    try
    {
        using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true))
        using(var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            serializer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, obj);
         }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Logger.WriteError(e.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

I also dispose of the StreamWriter that is created, the constructor I used has a `leaveOpen` flag which causes the underlying stream to not be closed when you dispose of the StreamWriter.