# Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 268435456 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to save some big data to database through a WCF service call. I am not able to invoke the service. Its throwing an error:

**Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 268435456 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low**

```
public async Task<int> UploadExportPackage(DTO.Upload.UploadPackage package)
{
    int result = await serviceProxy.UploadResultsAsync(package);
    return result;
}
```

Server side config:

```
    <!-- 
      Place limits on the amount of data that can be received in one go.
      This helps to protect the server from attack and abuse.
    -->
    <binding name="primaryBinding"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="6000000"
             maxBufferSize="6000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="12000000">

      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="6000000"
                    maxStringContentLength="6000000" />

      <!--
          Set the security mode. Apply at:
            - Transport layer
            - Message layer
      -->
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpsBinding>
</bindings>
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception no: 0
```

Next Exception:
Message:

Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 268435456 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low.

Stack trace:
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AllocateByteArray(Int32 size)
   at System.Runtime.InternalBufferManager.PooledBufferManager.TakeBuffer(Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferManagerOutputStream.Init(Int32 initialSize, Int32 maxSizeQuota, Int32 effectiveMaxSize, BufferManager bufferManager)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message, Boolean shouldRecycleBuffer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SendAsyncResult.SendWithoutChannelBindingToken()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SendAsyncResult.Send()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SendAsyncResult..ctor(HttpOutput httpOutput, HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage, Boolean suppressEntityBody, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.BeginSendCore(HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.SendWebRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.BeginSendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.BeginRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.RequestChannelSendAsyncResult.BeginSendCore(IRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ApplySecurityAndSendAsyncResult`1.OnSecureOutgoingMessageComplete(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ApplySecurityAndSendAsyncResult`1.Begin(Message message, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.BeginRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.BeginRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartSend(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishEnsureOpen(IAsyncResult result, Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartEnsureOpen(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishEnsureInteractiveInit(IAsyncResult result, Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartEnsureInteractiveInit()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.Begin()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginCall(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginCall(ServiceChannel channel, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2,TArg3](Func`6 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.CreateGenericTask[T](ServiceChannel channel, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] inputParameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.CreateGenericTask(ServiceChannel channel, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] inputParameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.CreateTask(ServiceChannel channel, IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeTaskService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at RossendaleClient8.DAL.RR.IRossendaleService.UploadResultsAsync(UploadPackage package)
   at RossendaleClient8.DAL.RR.RossendaleServiceClient.UploadResultsAsync(UploadPackage package)
   at RossendaleClient8.DAL.RossendaleServiceClient.d__13.MoveNext()

Next Exception:
Message:

Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Stack trace:   at System.Runtime.Fx.AllocateByteArray(Int32 size)

Comment: You may need to partition your data into smaller chunks and do multiple sends to the service.

Comment: @Kevin is there no way to send the whole lot? It's only about 200mb

Comment: Maybe add memory to the server. Don't think this will really fix the problem though. Just pushes out how long until it happens.

Comment: The problem is that the system has to allocate big chunks of memory repeatedly, and is running the server low on available memory before the GC can collect and free up all of that memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned before I have changed the TransferMode to "Streamed" but I have also increased the maximum buffer size. Increased the timeout and maxAllowedContent to 300mb to allow larger files to be uploaded. Works great now.

Answer (score 7):

If your binding allows, try using [TransferMode.Streamed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode(v=vs.110).aspx). You can also have a look at [BinaryMessageEncoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binarymessageencodingbindingelement(v=vs.110).aspx).
From MSDN:

> - Buffered transfers hold the entire message in a memory buffer until    the transfer is complete.
> - Streamed transfers only buffer the message    headers and expose the message body as a stream, from which smaller    portions can be
>     read at a time.

The default TransferMode is Buffered, so the whole message is loaded to memory. If you turn on Streamed TransferMode, you can manage the size of memory usage by editing value of MaxBufferSize.

BinaryMessageEncoding, in its turn, allows you to compress data, you send over network.
Here is a sample App.Config contents

```
 <customBinding>
    <binding name="primaryBinding" openTimeout="00:01:00"  closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
              sendTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00">
      <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpsTransport transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="6000000" 
                      maxBufferSize="6000000" maxBufferPoolSize="12000000" />          
    </binding>      
  </customBinding>
```

Same configuration in code

```
 private Binding GetBinding()
    {
        var config = new BindingElementCollection();            
        config.Add(new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement()
        {
            CompressionFormat = CompressionFormat.GZip,
        });
        config.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement()
        {
            MaxBufferPoolSize = 12000000,
            MaxBufferSize = 6000000,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 6000000,
            TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed,
        });

        var resultBinding = new CustomBinding(config)
        {
            OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        };

        return resultBinding;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware it might not be a suitable solution for everyone, but...

We had a similar issue recently. Only one of our dev had issues while debugging some code locally. Turns out he wasn't using the **64-bit** version of **IIS Express**.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried to send more than 50MB using WCF, but i'm pretty sure a 256MB+ file can easily cause problems like stated above, i'd suggest you try the following:

- Strip your file into smaller smaller chunks, e.g 50 MB per file
- Check the memory allocation of your service while trying to send the file, does it exceed the maximum of available memory on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

See also [OutOfMemoryException while populating MemoryStream: 256MB allocation on 16GB system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595061/outofmemoryexception-while-populating-memorystream-256mb-allocation-on-16gb-sys) :
The memory requested gets doubled step by step, and somewhen a contiguous chunk of extra memory can't be allocated - that's when you get the exception.