# DataSet Table giving "there is no row in position 0" error

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to retrieve an image from my database to appear as the background of my windows form. But the error "There are no rows at position 0" keeps appearing. I have tested it on other forms with the same code and it works fine. May I know what's wrong with the code below?

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select Background from Employee where EmployeeName='" + label10.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Background"] != System.DBNull.Value)
            { 
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((Byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Background"]);
            this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(ms);
```

Comment: try giving space between EmployeeName and =

Comment: Avoid string concatenation for SQL query, use parameterized query instead. Also you can create a `DataTable` and fill it from `SqlCommand`, then check with `DataTableName.Rows[0]["ColumnName"]`.

Answer (score 1):

you must need to check `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0` before trying code like this.

There is no need of dataset you can use DataTable directly.

One more change is make use of SQLParameter to pass value , rather than writing query like this , to avoid sql injection.

Make use of `using`  to dispose objects.

Comment: Do I implement a if else statement using `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0` and insert `if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Background"] != System.DBNull.Value)` into the if else statement?

Answer (score 0):

The exception message itself is pretty straightforward: `DataTable` inside `DataSet` contains no rows so that you can't pull any data from it. The `&&` operator can check both row existence & `DBNull.Value` condition (row count checking must be on the left):

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Background"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    // do another stuff
}
```

NB: You can simplify usage of `DataAdapter` and `DataSet` by using standard `SqlDataReader` and  [`DataTable.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this example:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Background from Employee where EmployeeName = @Name", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", label10.Text);

        var dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dt.Load(dr); // fill DataTable from reader
        }

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows[0]["Background"] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Background"]))
            {
                this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(ms);
            }
            // do another stuff
        }
        else
        {
            // do another stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. But how do I imply this section of my codes into yours                                                                                                                      `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Background"]);`                                                                                                        `this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(ms);`

Comment: I suggest putting `using` statement for `MemoryStream` initialization so that the byte array immediately disposed after converting it to bitmap, I had edited by adding example of that.

Comment: I tried the codes given but now i am getting the "Out of Memory" error.

Comment: @EGS: Can you provide size of byte array from `dt.Rows[0]["Background"]`? You can consider this issue as reference if you have large amount of RAM but experiencing 'out of memory': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595061/outofmemoryexception-while-populating-memorystream-256mb-allocation-on-16gb-sys.

Comment: Sorry I am really new to this but where do i provide the size and expand the memory in the program?